# PostgreSQL - How to remove duplicates when doing LEFT OUTER JOIN with WHERE clause?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I have 2 tables:

```
users table
+--------+---------+
| id     | integer |
+--------+---------+
| phone  | string  |
+--------+---------+
| active | boolean |
+--------+---------+

statuses table
+---------+---------+
| id      | integer |
+---------+---------+
| user_id | integer |
+---------+---------+
| step_1  | boolean |
+---------+---------+
| step_2  | boolean |
+---------+---------+
```

I'm doing `LEFT OUTER JOIN` `statuses` table on `users` table with `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT users.id, statuses.step_1, statuses.step_2
FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN statuses ON users.id = statuses.user_id
WHERE (users.active='f')
ORDER BY users.id DESC
```

**My problem**

There are some users that have same phone number inside the `users` table and I want remove the duplicate users based on the phone number.

I don't want to delete them from database. But just want to exclude them for this query only.

For example, say John (ID: 1) and Sara (ID: 2) shared same phone number (+6012-3456789), removing one of them, either John or Sara is fine for me.

**What I've tried but did not work?**

First:

```
SELECT DISTINCT users.phone
FROM users 
LEFT OUTER JOIN statuses ON users.id = statuses.user_id
WHERE (users.active='f')
ORDER BY users.id DESC
```

Second:

```
SELECT users.phone, COUNT(*)
FROM users
LEFT OUTER JOIN statuses ON users.id = statuses.user_id    
WHERE (users.active='f')
GROUP BY phone
HAVING COUNT(users.phone) > 1
```

Comment: what do you mean for "I want remove  one of them "  ?  you want delete   the related  row form table?

Comment: @scaisEdge not to delete, but just want to exclude them.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. Remember that SELECT DISTINCT applies to the whole selected rows.

Answer (score 5):

I would do this *before* doing the join.  In Postgres, `select distinct on` is a very useful construct:

```
SELECT u.id, s.step_1, s.step_2
FROM (SELECT distinct on (phone) u.*
      FROM users u
      WHERE u.active = 'f'
      ORDER BY phone
     ) u LEFT OUTER JOIN
     statuses s
     ON u.id = s.user_id
WHERE u.active = 'f'
ORDER BY u.id DESC;
```

`distinct on` returns one row for whatever is in parentheses.  In this case, that would be by `phone` (based on "I want remove the duplicate users based on the phone number").  Then, the `join` should not be showing these as duplicates.

Comment: Can you explain more what you're doing here?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way

Self Join the users table and join using phone numbers and filter any one of the duplicate name by comparison operator.

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT u.*
        FROM   users u
               JOIN users u1
                 ON u. u.phone = u1.phone -- to 
                    AND u.name >= u1.name) u
       LEFT OUTER JOIN statuses
                    ON users.id = statuses.user_id
WHERE  ( users.active = 'f' )
```

or use `ROW_NUMBER`

Generate row number for each phone numbers and filter the first phone number with row number as 1

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT u.*,
               Row_number()OVER(partition BY phone ORDER BY name) rn
        FROM   users u) u
       LEFT OUTER JOIN statuses
                    ON users.id = statuses.user_id
WHERE  ( users.active = 'f' )
       AND rn = 1
```

Comment: Can you explain more what you're doing here?

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin - Nothing much to explain here its a simple join.